# Git: Working with two divergent branches

Tags: git

I read numerous articles on this topic, but I'm still not sure how to proceed.

I have an application that has grown over the past 15 years; until now, the source code has been managed using another source control system. I'm planning to migrate to Git and intend to use a branching model like the one described [here](http://www.bitsnbites.eu/a-stable-mainline-branching-model-for-git/).

These branches need to be migrated from our current system to Git:

```
Current system | Git
---------------------------
Dev            | master
v1             | release/v1
```

v1 is a legacy release that needs to be maintained for now but will be deprecated at some point. It is very different from Dev and will never be merged entirely.

What I would like to do is:

- Initialize the repository
- Check in `Dev` code as `master`
- Switch to branch `release/v1` and replace all files with the current `v1` files, then push them to the server

Now comes the part that's unclear to me: I would like to be able to merge specific changes from `release/v1` to `master` in the future for parts of the application that are still similar enough, i.e. when fixing a bug in `v1`. To be able to do that, I need to do an initial upstream merge from `release/v1` to `master` where all differences are ignored, so `master` remains as it is and only changes after that point are taken into consideration.

Would `git merge -Xtheirs` be the way to go in this situation?

Thanks,
Jan

Edit:

I think I may have found my solution - not sure if it's elegant, but it seems to result in the correct state:

- Create repo and check in files for `master`
- Branch `release/v1`
- Replace contents of `release/v1` with files from previous SCM
- Checkout `master`
- merge with strategy **ours**: `git merge -s ours release/v1`

Comment: Can you tell me a little more about the specific changes you want to bring from release/v1?  Are they limited to specific files at the same paths in both branches?

Comment: Have you looked into cherry-picking commits?

Comment: I think I found my answer (although I read lots and lots of articles before asking here) - see my edit. Thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 1):

Consider *creating* your Git repository differently.  Start by creating the existing `v1` legacy version as the *first commit ever*.  The very first commit in any Git repository has an interesting property.

Let's start with how branches grow, on the assumption that you have an existing, working repository.  Imagine a small repository with only one named branch—`master`—and three commits.  The actual names of commits are big ugly hash IDs, but we'll work here with single uppercase letters.  (Our imaginary repository can only hold 26 commits!)

Let's draw the commits the way Git has them, too.  Each commit remembers, as its *parent*, the hash ID of the previous commit.  So since we have three commits, with the third one being commit `C`, commit `C` remembers commit `B` as its parent:

```
  <-B <-C
```

Of course `B` also has a parent, and it remembers that `A` is its parent:

```
A <-B <-C
```

But what is the parent commit for commit `A`?  The answer is: there is none.  It *can't* have a parent.  It's the first commit!  It is parent-less.  It is [*sui generis*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sui%20generis).  Git calls it a *root commit*.

The root commit is where all action starts—but Git works *backwards*, so it's really where all action *ends*.  The way Git remembers the hash ID of commit `C` is to store it in the name `master`.  Real hash IDs are big, ugly, and seemingly-random: there's no good way to remember them other than to just write them down, so Git writes them down in branch names like `master`.

Commits themselves are permanent, read-only, and incorruptible.<sup>1</sup>  Once you've made a commit, you can *never change it*.  So the hash IDs wired into each commit as the parent are unchangeable, and we don't really need to draw the arrows as arrows.  The hash IDs in *branch names*, though, are highly changeable!  So let's keep drawing those as arrows:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
```

We say that the name `master` *points to* commit `C`, and because `C` records `B`'s hash, `C` points to `B`.  `B` points to `A`, and `A`, as the root commit, points nowhere.

Now if we decide to add a *new* commit, we start with the following:

```
$ git checkout master
```

This attaches our HEAD to the name `master`.  Then we fuss with files and `git add` and `git commit` to make a new commit `D`.  `D`'s parent is `C`:

```
A--B--C   <-- master (HEAD)
       \
        D
```

The last (well, almost last) step of `git commit` is that Git writes `D`'s hash ID into the name to which `HEAD` is attached.  So `master` now points to `D`, not `C`:

```
A--B--C
       \
        D   <-- master (HEAD)
```

and we've thus created a new commit and added it to our `master` branch.

---

<sup>1</sup>The "forever" part is only mostly-true: a commit that cannot be *reached* by some external name, such as a branch name, is eventually garbage-collected and deleted.  The rest is guaranteed: you cannot change any existing Git object, and Git will detect (and complain about) any corruption when it notices that the *name* of the object no longer matches the cryptographic checksum of the object.  (The names *are* the cryptographic checksums, so if they do not match, corruption has occurred.)

---

#### How this applies to your situation

So, suppose we make the very first commit—our "commit `A`"—out of your v1 legacy version.  I'll omit all the Git commands, as you probably have those down:

```
A   <-- master (HEAD)
```

Now let's create a new *name*, say, `branch-v1`, that *also points to commit `A`.  We do this with the simple command:

```
$ git branch branch-v1
```

which gives us this:

```
A   <-- master (HEAD), branch-v1
```

Now we remove every file in the work-tree and the index:

```
$ git rm -r .
```

and copy in all the files from the development system, e.g.:

```
$ ssh development-system 'cd some/path; tar cf - .' | tar xf -
```

and then `git add` them all and `git commit`:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'import development version'
```

This makes our new commit `B`, and changes the name `master` to point to `B`.  `B`'s parent is `A`.  Let's draw it:

```
A   <-- branch-v1
 \
  B   <-- master (HEAD)
```

There's something very important about this graph drawing.  Commit `A` is on branch `branch-v1`, but it's *also* on `master`.  In Git, commits can be on *more than one branch at a time*.

#### Time marches on

Suppose it's now the next day (week, whatever) and there is a patch to v1.  You can now, on any Git repository that's a clone of this one (or on this one if you like), check out the `branch-v1` branch:

```
A   <-- branch-v1 (HEAD)
 \
  B--...--C   <-- master
```

We've made more commits on the main line (and maybe it's all fancied up with multiple branch names and so on, but commits `A` and `B` are certainly still in, shaped like this).  So now let's add and commit the updated v1 code:

```
A--D   <-- branch-v1 (HEAD)
 \
  B--...--C   <-- master
```

If we wish to take up the *changes* between snapshots `A` and `D`, it's now mostly-trivial (depending on just how radically different `C` is from `A`) to do so, using `git merge`.  Running:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge branch-v1
```

will tell Git to find the *latest shared / common commit* between the two branches `master` (to which we just attached our HEAD) and `branch-v1`.  So Git will search the history, following `C` back to `B` back to `A`, and following `D` to `A`.  Commit `A` is *on both branches*.  In fact, it's the latest such commit (the notion of *latest* here is rather wooly but I suspect you know what it means), so commit `A` is the *merge base* of commits `C` and `D`.

Git will therefore compare `A` vs `D`, to see *what changed* on `branch-v1` since we were last in sync there.  It will compare `A` vs `C`, to see what *we* changed on `master`, too.  Git will then combine these two sets of changes and make a new *merge commit,* on our current branch `master` (remember, our HEAD is attached to `master` now):

```
A----------D   <-- branch-v1
 \          \
  B--...--C--E   <-- master (HEAD)
```

The merge commit links back to the previous `HEAD`, i.e., `C`, as its first parent, and to the commit we merged (`D`) as its second parent.  (This parent numbering is important later, if you want it to be.)

If yet more change are made to `v1` we can incorporate them with another `git merge`.  We start with this, having picked up commit `F` somehow:

```
A----------D--F   <-- branch-v1
 \          \
  B--...--C--E   <-- master (HEAD)
```

and again run `git merge branch-v1`, which finds the *nearest common commit*: it looks at `F` which leads to `D`; it looks at `E` which leads to `C` and `D` both; and there we have our common commit: it's now `D`.  Git compares `D` vs `F` to see what they did, compares `D` vs `E` to see what we did, combines these changes, applies them to `D`'s source, and makes new merge commit `G`:

```
A----------D--F   <-- branch-v1
 \          \  \
  B--...--C--E--G   <-- master (HEAD)
```

Your branch flow model complicates all this up (for various reasons, mostly :-) good ones) but the fundamentals remain the same.

The reason we put v1 in as the first commit was to make sure that commit `A`, our root commit, which *contains the source* of v1, is on *all* branches.  That way anything that happens later can be compared to v1.

#### Tagging

You can find a root commit in a repository by doing graph traversal: when there's no more graph to traverse, you have reached a root commit.  As long as the graph has only *one* root (the normal case), that's *the* root.  But Git does let you create more root commits, and if you merge independent repositories, you will get extra roots that way as well.  In any case, walking the graph to *find* the root is a pain—so Git offers *tags* as well as branch names.

A branch name, as we saw, simply identifies one particular commit—but the name *moves* over time, as we add more commits to the branch.  A tag name does the same thing as a branch name, but unlike branch names, tag names *don't* move.  So once we've created the root commit on the `v1-branch` branch, we can *tag* that commit:

```
$ git tag v1.0
```

to make the string `v1.0` mean *that particular commit*.

Tags can be simple (a "lightweight tag") and just identify a commit directly, or fancied-up (an "annotated tag").  The fancy one carries extra data, and then identifies the commit.  The use of either tag is basically the same—`v1.0` is another name for the raw hash ID—so choose an annotated tag if you want to add the extra data that an annotated tag brings.

(There's another difference when merging against an annotated tag, but I'll skip that for now.)

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your elaborate reply. I'll have to read that again (and probably again after that) next week at work to understand all of it :)

Answer (score 0):

Porting history from another SCM system is cumbersome.  Luckily, since you are starting with two fixed and well-understood points and want to draw a deliberate and gradual path between them, there is an easier way than working with merge commands.

Start by establishing the branches `master` and `v1` as you describe.  Then, bring changes from `v1` into `master` one file at a time.

Given `src/someFile.cpp` present in both `master` and `release/v1`, start by checking out `master` and then [ask Git to bring in the other branch's version](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout-emgitcheckoutemlttree-ishgt--ltpathspecgt82308203).

Execute `git checkout release/v1 -- src/someFile.cpp` from the root of the repository.  The syntax `git checkout branch1 -- fileA` tells git to bring `fileA` into the current branch from `branch1`, overwriting any existing file by the same name.

History is preserved as usual; each time you do this inter-branch checkout command, it stages a change which must then be committed.  You may do this for multiple files. then commit them all at once.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think I didn't quite make myself clear in the question. `master`and `v1` are supposed to remain in the state that they're currently in. `v1` will be deprecated at some point, so that's Ok. They're just too different to be fully merged.

What I want is to get Git into a state where it doesn't care about all the  initial differences between the two branches anymore - but will still let me merge future changes in `v1` into master.

I think I may have found my solution: merge with merging strategy "ours": `git merge -s ours release/v1`

Comment: I'm glad you worked it out.  I would second @dimwittedanimal's comment elsewhere and say you may also be interested in the 'git cherry-pick' command.